# How To Code A BlackBox in Python Using Homomorphic or...?

Tags: python, encryption, encryption-symmetric

I need a "blackbox" coded in Python...

...Meaning, code that receives unencrypted inputs, runs those inputs through an encrypted algorithm, then sends out unencrypted outputs.

I just ran across this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption

But have no idea where to start making something like that in Python.

My questions for encryption experts:

1. Can it be done using Python?
2. If so what kind of performance loss can I expect running encrypted
   code?
3. Do you have some simple examples I can learn from?

Thanks

Comment: Homomorphic encryption is usually public key encryption. The computation is always performed on the encrypted inputs and the outputs are also always encrypted. Perhaps you should think about what you want to achieve first. There are many schemes for doing this. Which one do you want to implement (don't expect full solutions here)? Btw, *Charm crypto* should have some homomorphic schemes implemented.

Comment: I need to protect the algorithm.  The algorithm has a high IP value.  The inputs/outputs don't need to be protected, it's the logic that has the value.

Comment: So, you want a white-box implementation of your algorithm or obfuscation. Both mean that the code remains unintelligible when reverse-engineered. Also, in that regard, homomorphic encryption is something completely different.